# Automatically click on each tab in webbrowser and click on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

Given a set of webpages open in a browser all from the same website each with a submit button, is it possible to write something that would go to each tab in turn and click on the submit button?

I am wondering if something like that could be done with a userscript manager, like Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey.

Or, alternatively, is there some way that when the webpage is opened instead of just opening the page it could open it, wait for it to load, and then press the submit button?

The webpage is opened via a `form`, not with `window.open()`:

```html
<form target="_blank" action="https://acoustid.org/edit/toggle-track-mbid" method="POST">
    <input name="state" value="1" hidden="">
    <input name="track_id" value="9509889" hidden="">
    <input name="mbid" value="6573f01d-0df5-442d-90c3-a69783c217c3" hidden="">
    <input type="submit" value="Unlink">
</form>
```

[Here's the website](http://reports.albunack.net/new_acoustid_report1_1.html). Click <kbd>Unlink</kbd> to open a new window and view the form (*you need an account*):

[image: unlink MBID form]

Its HTML is:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/edit/toggle-track-mbid">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="note_i">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="note" id="name_i"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="mbid" value="b3350a3b-b8e0-45c0-8289-006451788849">
    <input type="hidden" name="track_id" value="12211538">
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Are all windows/tabs open _BY_ the same browser window? If that answer is "no" - the overall answer is "no, not from JavaScript running on a browser".

Comment: @RandyCasburn  Yes they are

Comment: The new windows are opened via a form post (the server opens the page). So there is no way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @double-beep thanks I have a different solution now, I manage to submit the form so that I no longer need to press submit on the form, as the orginal form submission has enough infomation for the server to act on it without needing to go to the other page

Answer (score 0):

The `form` can be submitted without actually opening another one in a new tab. The difference between the <kbd>Unlink</kbd> and <kbd>Submit</kbd> forms is that the latter has two new values: `submit` set to `1` (that is, unlink when form submitted) and `note`, a comment to explain the unlinking.

Since the question was posted, though, you've added the `submit=1` parameter to the first form, so that a track can be directly unlinked by clicking the <kbd>Unlink</kbd> button.

Here's a solution that automates the process a bit:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Submit all forms
// @version      0.1
// @description  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70227065
// @author       double-beep
// @match        http://reports.albunack.net/*.html
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    async function submitAllForms() {
        const forms = document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr > :nth-child(2) > form');

        const formPromises = [...forms].map(form => {
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            if (!formData.get('submit')) { // old version of the website
                formData.set('submit', '1');
            }

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                    method: 'POST', // post
                    url: form.action,
                    data: formData,
                    onload: resolve,
                    onerror: reject
                });
            });
        });

        await Promise.all(formPromises);
    }

    const submitButton = document.createElement('input');
    submitButton.value = 'Submit forms';
    submitButton.type = 'submit';
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        submitButton.disabled = true;
        submitButton.innerText = 'Please wait...';

        await submitAllForms();

        submitButton.disabled = false;
        submitButton.value = 'Re-submit forms';
    });

    document
        .querySelector('table')
        .previousElementSibling
        .insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', submitButton);
});
```

Only problem is - `track_id`s don't match and there's nothing the userscript can do about it.